# How do I get specific JSON item?

Tags: json, stock

I am trying to read through this data but I am stuck on something very very basic. Can't seem to find a way on my own. Let me know if anyone can help.

Code:

```
const api = require('indian-stock-exchange');
const nse = api.NSE
const bse = api.BSE

nse.getIndices().then(
    function(response) {
        var data = response.data
        console.log(data)
    }
)
```

Output:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      timeVal: 'Nov 27, 2020 15:33:24',
      indexName: 'NIFTY 50',
      previousClose: '12,987.00',      
      open: '13,012.05',
      high: '13,035.30',
      low: '12,914.30',
      last: '12,968.95',
      percChange: '-0.14',
      yearHigh: '13,145.85',
      yearLow: '7,511.10',
      indexOrder: '0.00'
    },
    {
      timeVal: 'Nov 27, 2020 15:33:24',
      indexName: 'NIFTY NEXT 50',
      previousClose: '30,186.05',
      open: '30,316.45',
      high: '30,591.00',
      low: '30,121.35',
      last: '30,334.40',
      percChange: '0.49',
      yearHigh: '30,591.00',
      yearLow: '18,384.05',
      indexOrder: '1.00'
    },
    {
      timeVal: 'Nov 27, 2020 15:33:24',
      indexName: 'NIFTY IT',
      previousClose: '21,859.90',
      open: '21,879.15',
      high: '21,972.95',
      low: '21,701.30',
      last: '21,764.90',
      percChange: '-0.43',
      yearHigh: '22,619.00',
      yearLow: '10,991.25',
      indexOrder: '2.00'
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get only Nifty50 (the first array) results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var firstObject = data['data'][0];
```

Will give you the array's first element. Then you can access the values like this:

```
var time = firstObject['timeVal']
```

or:

```
var time = firstObject.timeVal
```